# Galois group of $\mathbb{C}(t)/\mathbb{C}(t^{20})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, solution-verification

Let $t$ be a variable. Can I say that $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is the splitting field of the separable polynomial $f(x)=x^{20}-t^{20}\in\mathbb{C}(t^{20})$, for then the Galois group is cyclic of order $20$? More specifically, the roots of $f(x)$ should be $t,\zeta_{20}t,\ldots,\zeta_{20}^{19}t$ where $\zeta_{20}$ is some primitive $20^\text{th}$ root of unity. But $\zeta_{20}$ is already in $\mathbb{C}$, so the splitting field is just $\mathbb{C}(t)$. The elements of the Galois group are just maps $\sigma_k:t\mapsto\zeta_{20}^kt$ for $0\leq k\leq 19$. Clearly $\sigma_1$ (or any $\sigma_r$ for $(r,20)=1$) is a generator for the Galois group, so it is cyclic on $20$ elements. Is this really all there is to it, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that’s it precisely. Any time you have the $n$-th roots of unity in your smaller field, adjoining an $n$-th root will give you a Galois, cyclic extension of the smaller, of degree dividing $n$. In this case, you want to think of $t^{20}=T$, and the smaller field is $\Bbb C(T)$, the fraction field of the PID $\Bbb C[T]$, and your equation is $x^{20}-T$, over that PID, clearly Eisenstein, so irreducible, and your field extension degree is $20$.